# Connecting a Database to a Xamarin iOS and Android mobile app

Tags: database, xamarin, mobile, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am building my own app to learn a new skill. I have a database of "Tickets" I just want to be able to press a certain button, which will then send a SQL statement to the DB, and return with all of the tickets it calls for. I understand this can be done with Web Services but that seems like overkill for just viewing a one table. The problem is, I cannot figure out where to put the connection strings to set up the connection. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: @MihailDuchev thank you, I will look at it deeper later tonight, but, I am trying to see how to do it without Web Services. The database I'm using is paid for through a company, and their Web Service calls get muddied up really quick. I'm more looking for a way to make a straight connection to the DB for just some quick views through SQL statements. Thank you again though!

Comment: It is **never** a good idea to try to connect to a db directly. That's why there are these services.

Comment: While yes, I agree, all I'm doing is a simple view. I'm just looking for a small thing to be able to get reports. Nothing crazy.

Comment: "where to put the connection strings" - if you're just trying to learn, and are ignoring the prevailing wisdom about the terribly bad idea this is, just hardcode the connection string.

Comment: @Jason thanks, but again it is one simple 2 button view that uses two different SQL statements to view tickets, it is pointless to go through the process for the smallest view.

Comment: that's why I told you to "just hardcode the connection string"

Comment: And I was telling you my reasoning for "ignoring the prevailing wisdom about the terribly bad idea it is".

Comment: This might help you, just look for a nuget package that will help you connect to your sql database in the exact same way, and then you will find your answer https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/87899/how-to-connect-mysql-cross-platform . Please note that anyone who gets hold of your app, will be able to see the connection string if their device is jailbroken